# didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: not fetching from server

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, completionhandler

I want push notifications to get my app to fetch stuff from the server. I use RESTKit.
I'm trying to implement `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` and then do my REST request (which is a block). I can see in the logs that the request is sent, but then there is no answer. I guess it's because the app is in the background. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with blocks.
my code is:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
{
     NSString *type = [userInfo valueForKey:@"type"];
     if ([type isEqualToString:@"message"]) {
         [self.viewController fetchFromServerWithSuccesBlock:^{
             NSLog(@"succes block");
             completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
         } withFailBlock:^{
             NSLog(@"fail block");
             completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
         }];
     }
}
```

This way the `completionHandler` gets called when the block of my request is finished.